# ipad scrolling is not working for draggable items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ipad, scroll, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a list of draggable items. I use [Jquery UI draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) . Now I am trying to scroll (container is limited, so I need to scroll to drag my expected item) but it is not working.

```
$elt.draggable
  cursor: 'crosshair'
  revert: 'invalid'
  delay: 500
  distance: 10
  start: (event, ui) ->
    $(this).css('display', 'inline-block')
    ui.helper.width($(this).width() + 1)
    $(this).css('color', 'green')
  stop: ->
    if $(this).data('type') == 'bundle'
      $(this).css('color', '#40A0FF')
    else
      $(this).css('color', 'white')

    $(this).css('display', 'block')
```

I try to implement same draggable at [here](http://codepen.io/hasanuzzaman/pen/ORRZpP/) where you can see that mouse clicking scrolling is not working ( I am working on ipad only, so mouse scroll wheel is useless). If I remove draggable then list scroll as my expected. Thank you for any kind of help.

N.B: As far as I understand, draggable `scroll` option is not my case because I am talking about scroll(normal ipad touch scroll for overflow) before dragging not during dragging. My list without `draggable` are scrolling fine.